# How to collapse div towards center using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Can someone suggest a plugin or method in jQuery to collapse elements to center. I've seen it on websites but searched google without luck, I want the element to quickly collapse in center point.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best plugin is to use jQuery UI Clip effect.
Click on the green box to see the effect:

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Clip